# HOWTF do you twerp!

Tags: twrp, samsung-galaxy-note-3, ads

Samsung Galaxy note 3
sm-n9005 hltexx
lollipop 5.0
UK /international
open
please excuse my stupidity and ignorance.
but howtf do i get to use twrp when i bootload to recovery??

every time I try twrp my phone... recovery mode seems to disappear and i get odin mode downloading dont turn off your device

no..volume up OR down with home and power will not do it
neither will adb 
nor any other tutorial i found and a few tutorials later and im fxn exhausted|

been trying to do this since like 3 AM and its 13:21
should it actually be this hard?
why couldnt it just work using the official twrk app instructions?

im starting to think forget twrp can anyone recommend a recovery bootloader?
or should i not?

ALL I WANT IN LIFE IS STEP FOUR OF THIS GUIDE!!!! Am i over complicating something?Am i asking for too much? have i understood the instructions wrong?

https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-patched-ad-free-youtube-apks-t3449312

is there some super simple way to never get ads on my phone somewhere else?
SPECIALLY YOUTUBE

Answer (score 0):

Flash the BTU version for your ROM. Download and full Instructions on [fw.updato.com](https://updato.com/firmware-archive-select-model?record=F6EC8F56F6E811E89F15FA163EE8F90B)

Flash TWRP (tar) via Odin AP. Download and full instructions on [forum.xda-developers.com](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-3/development/recovery-twrp-3-2-1-1-t3746760)

Immediately reboot into recovery without ever booting into system. If you boot into system this will brick your phone and you have to flash stock rom again.

Format Data from TWRP recovery (Wipe -> Format Data -> type yes). reboot recovery.

Now copy the following files via USB (MTP) to Internal Storage.

Install the no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip or [Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3817389) from TWRP. reboot recovery.

Install [Magisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445) zip. reboot system. wait for the boot about 20 minutes. you are rooted now.

Note: If you see errors in TWRP, goto Advanced -> Copy Log, get the recovery.log from USB (MTP) and find the more detailed Error Messages